# Rowspan for gantt chart in anychart

Tags: html-table, gantt-chart, anychart

How do I group two rows together in gantt chart data grid in anychart as can be seen below?

[image]

I tried searching API and found `rowspan` for table but haven't found for gantt chart.

Answer (score 0):

AnyChart's Gantt chart doesn't have a built-in rowspan feature for the data grid. However, you can achieve a similar effect by merging cells using HTML/CSS or you can play with the mergeCells method of the data grid object.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the exact behavior is not possible with conventional methods, but you could use the [baselines](https://docs.anychart.com/Gantt_Chart/Project_Chart#baselines_(planned)) to show the planned against actual dates for a regular or parent task. You could use the `baselineStart` `baselineEnd` data fields to set the baselines start and end, as shown below.

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {

  // create data
  var data = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "Development",
    baselineStart: "2018-01-12",
    baselineEnd: "2018-03-04",
    actualStart: "2018-01-15",
    actualEnd: "2018-03-10",
    children: [{
        id: "1_1",
        name: "Analysis",
        baselineStart: "2018-01-12",
        baselineEnd: "2018-01-25",
        actualStart: "2018-01-15",
        actualEnd: "2018-01-25"
      },
      {
        id: "1_2",
        name: "Design",
        baselineStart: "2018-01-20",
        baselineEnd: "2018-01-31",
        actualStart: "2018-01-20",
        actualEnd: "2018-02-04"
      },
      {
        id: "1_3",
        name: "Meeting",
        actualStart: "2018-02-05",
        actualEnd: "2018-02-05"
      },
      {
        id: "1_4",
        name: "Implementation",
        baselineStart: "2018-02-01",
        baselineEnd: "2018-02-19",
        actualStart: "2018-02-05",
        actualEnd: "2018-02-24"
      },
      {
        id: "1_5",
        name: "Testing",
        baselineStart: "2018-02-20",
        baselineEnd: "2018-03-05",
        actualStart: "2018-02-25",
        actualEnd: "2018-03-10"
      }
    ]
  }];

  // create a data tree
  var treeData = anychart.data.tree(data, "as-tree");

  // create a chart
  var chart = anychart.ganttProject();

  // set the data
  chart.data(treeData);

  // configure the scale
  chart.getTimeline().scale().maximum("2018-03-15");

  // set the container id
  chart.container("container");

  // initiate drawing the chart
  chart.draw();

  // fit elements to the width of the timeline
  chart.fitAll();
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.1/js/anychart-base.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.1/js/anychart-gantt.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.1/js/anychart-exports.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.1/js/anychart-ui.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```